# Errors faced when using PYQT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pylint

I've recently started to use PyQT5. However, I'm facing several errors which are being generated yet the application it self is still working. All of the errors are for undefined variables for PyQT related modules.

E.G. "Undefined variable 'QApplication' pylint(undefined-variable).

As im following a tutorial with no real expertise in PyQT or pylint im unsure as to what this is and how detrimental this is to my project. Can this be solved, if so how? if not, is there a possible work around?

Below is not the exact code I originally reported this error on (I'm only following a tutorial therefore none of it is complex code) however the following produces the exact same error which suggests it is indeed not the script itself and is likely a visual studio code or Pylint issue.

```
import sys
import time
# Self explanatory.
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

# Create QApplication Object. Something all applications must have one of.
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
```

Comment: You snapshot doesn't show the top of the file; hard to guess if your code is wrong or pylint is badly configured. Although if your code works, it's probably a pylint config issue.

Comment: Please post your code and stack trace (error descriptions) *as text in the post*, not as a link to a screenshot.

Comment: As an aisde, you may want to consider using PySide instead of PyQt as your Python binding for Qt, since PySide is getting integrated into Qt: https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python

Comment: I have updated the post as requested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the PyQT5. It is the problem with VS Code. The PyLint in your VS Code build can't understand the PyQT5 variables. It is because Pylint doesn't support Dynamic Modules like PyQT5.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/261

To solve the problem follow these rules:

1. Go to the VS Code User directory normally located at following path

   - **Windows** : %APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json
   - **macOS**   : $HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json
   - **Linux**   : $HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json
2. Open settings.json file.
3. Write following command at the end of the file:

```
   {
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5"]
   }
```

4. Save the file.
5. Run your code and tell me if the error is fixed or not.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. In fact it produced some white space errors too.

Comment: I had accidently written cv2 instead of PyQt5.  Try again with replacing cv2 with PyQt5 after --extension-pkg-whitelist= .I already edited the answer.

Comment: I have made the changes as requested and the error still remains.

Comment: @ChadLangford Try [changing your linter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_specific-linters) to `flake8`. According to [this vscode issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2817#issuecomment-428408443), the problem is specific to pylint.

Comment: try putting "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5"]  in already present { } instead of creating new ones.

Comment: and don't forget to put comma at the end of second last line while entering "python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5"] in already present brackets.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head Hussain. Thank you very much. I appreciate the help!